# $\mu$-almost everywhere convergence and $\mu$-null set

Tags: real-analysis

My question is about $\mu$-almost everywhere convergence and $\mu$-null set.

I read the following statement ($\mu$ is a measure):

> Suppose $f_n \rightarrow f \ \ \mu$-almost everywhere, then $\exists$ a $\mu-$null set $N \in \Sigma$ s.t. $f_n 1_N \rightarrow f$ everywhere .
>   1. $\Sigma$ is a sigma-algebra.
>   2. $1_N$ is an indicator function.

I'm confused by this statement. How could I explain the part after the ","?

Suppose $\Sigma$ is not trivial.

---

I see this statement in the following:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem

in the part of the proof of "Bounded convergence theorem" (last two lines)

[image]

Comment: Do you mean $f_n1_N\to f1_N$ everywhere?

Comment: Yes, you can say that.

Comment: It's simply not true. Let $\mu(1)=1$ and $\mu(0)=0$. Then as long as $f(0)\ne \lim f_n(0)$, the result doesn't hold.

Comment: I try to make my problem more clearer

Comment: $f_n 1_{N^c}$ converges to $f$ for $x \in N^c$ (where $N^c$ is the complement of $N$). Convergence does not occur on $N$, typically.